# Error creating Excel.Application object System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio

I got the next code in form application using vb in visual studio 2019, when i execute the sub cmd_data_Click i got the next error

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).'

How can i solved?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class frm_main
    Private Sub cmd_nuevo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_nuevo.Click
        frm_newPt1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmd_activos_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_activos.Click
        frm_activos.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_seguimientoQRQC.Click
        frm_selectionQRQC.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmd_data_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_data.Click
        Dim APP As New Excel.Application
        Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim cadena As New OleDbConnection
        Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ods As New DataSet
        Dim consulta As String
        Dim registro As Integer

        If Dir("C:\QRQC\DataQRQC.xlsx", vbArchive) <> "" Then
            Kill("C:\Scripts\DataQRQC.xlsx")
        End If


        cadena.ConnectionString = conexion
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\Users\2460473\Desktop\QRQC\DataQRQC.xlsx", "C:\QRQC\DataQRQC.xlsx")
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open("C:\QRQC\DataQRQC.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("QRQC")
        consulta = "Select *From QRQC"
        oda = New OleDbDataAdapter(consulta, cadena)
        ods.Tables.Add("QRQC")
        oda.Fill(ods.Tables("QRQC"))
        registro = ods.Tables("QRQC").Rows.Count
        For i = 0 To registro - 1 Step 1
            worksheet.Range("A" & (i + 2)).Value = ods.Tables("QRQC").Rows(i).Item("ID_QRQC")
        Next
        workbook.Save()
        APP.Quit()
        ods.Tables.Clear()
        MsgBox("El documento fue generado en la siguiente ruta C:\QRQC\DataQRQC.xlsx", vbInformation, "Aviso")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is bound to happen: you're not releasing any of the COM objects you create. `APP.Quit()` doesn't mean anything here, since it cannot *quit*.

Comment: Take a look at : [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)

Comment: see: [When CoCreateInstance returns 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200905112832/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adioltean/when-cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-co_e_server_exec_failure)